# Comparing dates when using reduceByKey

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-collections

In scala I have seen `reduceByKey((x: Int , y Int) => x + y)`, but I want to iterate a value as string and do some comparison. Are we able to use `reduceByKey` using `reduceByKey(x: String , y: String)`?

Code:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Spark AVRO Read")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf) 
val inPath= "/home/053764/episodes.avro" 
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc) 
val df = sqlContext.read.avro(inPath) 

val rows: RDD[Row] = df.rdd 
val doc = df.select("doctor").rdd.map(r => r(0) val docsss = rows.map(r => (r(2), r(1))) 

val reduce = docsss.reduceByKey((first, second) => { 
val firstDate = LocalDateTime.parse(first) 
val secondDate = LocalDateTime.parse(second) 
if (firstDate.isBefore(secondDate)) first else second 
})
```

Please let me know how to iterate the value as string using reduce by key

Comment: Strings aren't associative in nature. What do you mean by "*iterate a value as string"*? How is that related to `reduceByKey`? (I also think you're referring to Spark).

Comment: If I get a key,value pair lets say Key : 100 Value : 2010/01/01 , 2010/20/20 , I want to compare the 2 dates for the same key 100. So I thought we can do it using Reducebykey.

Comment: And what have you tried doing with `reduceByKey` so far? Are you unsure how to parse the dates?

Comment: I tried to get the value as string and do the comparison, but reducebykey is allowing only INT as value.

Comment: Scala doesn't have a `reduceByKey` method. Perhaps you mean Apache Spark?

Comment: Yep, I am using reducebykey in spark using scala

Comment: " reducebykey is allowing only INT as value". That;'s not the case with reduceByKey so you're doing something wrong. Post what you've tried, and people might be able to help

Comment: I want to compare a different values between same key :
map("Robert" , "2010/01/02" , "John" , "2011/02/02" , "Robert" , "2011/02/20")

I am trying to compare : Values between Key Robert : 2010/01/02 & 2011/02/20

Comment: And `reduceByKey` does not take two arguments, `Int` or not, but a function taking two values and returning one. So I think it's essential you post some code

Comment: `reduceByKey` doesn't do the comparisons. The function you pass to it does. So as @YuvalItzchakov says, are you really asking how to compare two dates that are represented as Strings?

Comment: Yes @The Archetypal Paul , I want to compare 2 dates for the same key

Answer (score 1):

[`PairRDDFunctions.reduceByKey`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions) in Spark works on any RDD in the form of `RDD[(K, V)]`. `reduceByKey` will take type `K` (which can be properly compared using an equality check) and invoke a function `(V, V) => V` for any type `V`.

Here is a short example of a tuple of (Int, String) where you reduce two strings:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, "01/01/2014"), (1, "02/01/2014")))
rdd.reduceByKey((first, second) => {
  val firstDate = LocalDateTime.parse(first)
  val secondDate = LocalDateTime.parse(second)

  if (firstDate.isBefore(secondDate)) first else second
})
```

---

### Edit:

As @TheArchetypalPaul rightly points out, since the dates are in constant format of year/zero-padded-month/zero-padded-day you can take advantage of [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) and compare the two `String` values instead of parsing them to `DateTime` objects. Which basically reduces the code to:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, "01/01/2014"), (1, "02/01/2014")))
rdd.reduceByKey((first, second) => if (first > second) first else second)
```

Note this does limit you to the certain format you're using. If that changes, you'd be better off using the first version which created a `LocalDateTime` object for the dates.

Comment: In the op's case, since the dates' string representation is sensibly ordered ("2010/01/01"), the Strings can just be compared directly. But your code is a lot more flexible.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Because the dates are year/zero-padded-month/zero-padded-day, the lexigraphical ordering of just comparing the strings is the same as converting it to Dates and comparing them

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. Edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you Yuval, I tried your logic to implement on my frame work.but I am getting error (type mismatch; found : Any required: CharSequence

Comment: val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Spark AVRO Read")   val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)     val inPath= "/home/053764/episodes.avro"  
  val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)      val df = sqlContext.read.avro(inPath)  val rows: RDD[Row] = df.rdd  val doc = df.select("doctor").rdd.map(r => r(0)  val docsss = rows.map(r => (r(2),r(1)))       val reduce = docsss.reduceByKey((first, second) =>  { val firstDate = LocalDateTime.parse(first)  val secondDate = LocalDateTime.parse(second)  if (firstDate.isBefore(secondDate)) first else second  })

Comment: i am getting type mismatch; found : Any required: CharSequence for the first and second

Comment: @jk7 What is the type of your `doc` variable?

Comment: Please ignore the field doc, please see the below one :val docsss  = rows.map(r => (r(2),r(1)))

Comment: @jk7 What is it's type?

Comment: @jk7, please post your code in a question, maybe a new question. Doing this in comments is painful to watch

Comment: I didn't declare any type, when I tried to declare a type for Docsss as string : val docsss : String = rows.map(r => (r(2),r(1))) its telling r type mismatch; found : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Any, Any)] required: String

Answer (score 0):

I didn't declare any type, when I tried to declare a type for Docsss as string :

```
 val docsss : String = rows.map(r => (r(2),r(1)))
```

its telling

```
  type mismatch; found : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Any, Any)]
                 required: String    val rows: RDD[Row] = df.rdd
```

Comment: No, a question, not an answer :(

Comment: And why would you declare it to be a string? It isn't, obviously?

Comment: you mean you want me to add a new question?

Comment: You are already asking it as a question,just distributed over lots of comments. But really, I think you need to go and think through  Yuval Itzchakov's answer, as you're using him as a Scala debugger right now, not really fair to him.